# Is it possible to create a message using Microsoft Graph with a different sent/received date?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm working on an application that needs to be able to insert messages into an O365 mailbox with particular dates (similar to a mail migration).  I created a version using IMAP with MailKit, and that was a simple matter of setting the date property on the message object:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(NameGenerator.AnyName(), EmailAddressGenerator.AnyEmailAddress()));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(m_O365UserID));
message.Subject = StringGenerator.AnyStringOfSizeAndCase(NumberGenerator.RandomNumberBetween(20, 100), CaseType.TitleCase);
BodyBuilder builder = new BodyBuilder
{
    HtmlBody = LipsumGenerator.GenerateHtml(NumberGenerator.RandomNumberBetween(3, 10))
};
message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
DateTime t = DateTimeGenerator.AnyDateBetween(m_startDate, DateTime.Now);
t = t.Add(DateTimeGenerator.AnyTime());
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(t);
message.Date = dto;
```

I was also able to do this in the past with EWS, but I needed to set some extended properties to do it, like this:

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition deliveryTime = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0E06, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition clientSubmitTime = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0039, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition flags = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
```

```
EmailMessage m = new EmailMessage(m_exchangeService);
m.From = EmailAddressGenerator.AnyEmailAddress();
m.ToRecipients.Add(m_emailAddress);
DateTime t = DateTimeGenerator.AnyDateBetween(startDate, DateTime.Now);
t = t.Add(DateTimeGenerator.AnyTime());
m.SetExtendedProperty(deliveryTime, t);
m.SetExtendedProperty(clientSubmitTime, t);
m.SetExtendedProperty(flags, 1);
```

Both of these approaches can backdate a message to any point that I need.  In this case I'm just populating a mailbox with test data to validate the API calls.  Trying to do the same thing in graph like this:

```
                Microsoft.Graph.Message message = new Microsoft.Graph.Message();
                message.From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = EmailAddressGenerator.AnyEmailAddress(), Name = NameGenerator.AnyName() } };
                message.ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>();
                message.ToRecipients.Append(new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = m_O365UserID } });
                message.Subject = StringGenerator.AnyStringOfSizeAndCase(NumberGenerator.RandomNumberBetween(20, 100), CaseType.TitleCase);

                DateTime t = DateTimeGenerator.AnyDateBetween(m_startDate, DateTime.Now);
                t = t.Add(DateTimeGenerator.AnyTime());
                DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(t);

                message.ReceivedDateTime = dto;
                message.SentDateTime = dto;
                message.CreatedDateTime = dto;
                message.LastModifiedDateTime = dto;
```

timestamps the message as of the submission time.  I thought I needed to set the same Mapi properties on the message as with EWS, but so far I haven't found a way to do that.  I looked into extended properties as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), which says they can be referenced by a type and MAPI property tag.  [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0) says that extended properties can be created on new objects:

> To create one or more extended properties in a new resource instance, use the same REST request as creating the instance, and include the properties of the new resource instance and extended property in the request body.

I tried that like this:

```
                Dictionary<string, object> extendedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                extendedProperties.Add("SystemTime 0x0E06",dto.DateTime);
                extendedProperties.Add("SystemTime 0x0039", dto.DateTime);
                extendedProperties.Add("Integer 0x3591",1);

                message.Body = new ItemBody { ContentType = BodyType.Html, Content = LipsumGenerator.GenerateHtml(NumberGenerator.RandomNumberBetween(3, 10)), AdditionalData=extendedProperties};
```

Which throws an exception:

> The property 'SystemTime 0x0E06' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemBody'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

I also can't directly create anything on message.SingleValueExtendedProperties, and the same exception happens if I omit SystemTime and just try to set the property with the hex value.  I'd like to be able to support Graph for this application-is there any way that anyone knows of to create messages with custom send/receive dates?  If I was able to do it in EWS, I'd expect that the newer API should be able to do the same thing.

**Edit**
@Glen's answer works.  I'd tried the same thing, but still had a second definition of the property that I was trying to add to the message body, which was what actually caused the exception.  The only other thing to add to his answer is that the time format for the property needs to be in a very specific format, so you can format a standard DateTimeOffset to a mapi compatible time like this:

```
string mapiTime = $"{dto.UtcDateTime.Year}-{dto.UtcDateTime.Month.ToString("D2")}-{dto.UtcDateTime.Day.ToString("D2")}T{dto.UtcDateTime.TimeOfDay.ToString()}.0{dto.Offset.Hours.ToString("D2")}:00";
message.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage()
{
    new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "Integer 0x0E07",Value = "1" },
    new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "SystemTime 0x0039", Value = mapiTime },
    new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "SystemTime 0x0E06",Value = mapiTime }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```
        Microsoft.Graph.Message message = new Microsoft.Graph.Message();
        message.From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "blah@blah.com", Name = "blah" } };
        message.ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>() { new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "ToBalh@blah.com" } } };
        message.Subject = "Blah";
        message.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage()
        {
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "Integer 0x0E07",Value = "1" },
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "SystemTime 0x0039", Value = "2020-05-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00" },
            new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty {Id = "SystemTime 0x0E06",Value = "2020-05-12T10:10:47.2048+10:00" }
        };
        var SaveMessage = graphClient.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.Request().AddAsync(message).Result;
```

works for me okay

Comment: Thanks-that worked!  I'd tried the same thing, but forgotten to remove the previous attempt at setting the properties in the message body, so that masked the real issue.  I updated my original post with a note on formatting a DTO to be compatible, since the formatting seems to be very particular.

Comment: @ChrisBardon Is there a way to add SingleValueExtendedProperty using MimeMessage?